# Interactive tool for plotting data points with filter and search capabilities

Tags: data-visualization, interactive-visualization

I am used to make my data plots with R and to save the results to static files but now I have a data set with far too many data points and I need to explore it. Due to this I need a recommendation for an interactive tool for plotting (2D) data. It should be able to interactively filter and search points by additional features associated with the data points (e.g. name). Additionally it should run on a GNU/Linux system. Any hints? Many thanks in advance.

Cheers, Konrad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For interactively exploring higher dimensional cluster solutions I have used [GGobi](http://www.ggobi.org/) in the past, it may also be appropriate to your case.

It takes some time getting used to, but it interfaces nicely with R and runs on GNU/Linux.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. Sorry, I cannot upvote yet.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by interactive?  R is pretty interactive as is, you can plot subsets of the data almost as easily as plotting the whole dataset.  There are tools in R to give even more interactivity, the `playwith` package may be of help, the `zoomplot` function in the TeachingDemos package is another.  The `tkexamp` function in the TeachingDemos package helps with creation of a gui for plotting functions, you can write a function that plots just those subsets based on arguments that you are interested in, then `tkexamp` can create a gui where changing sliders or entering information in boxes will update the plot accordingly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, Greg. I should have give a more precise description what I want. I was thinking more of a graphical selection tool which GGobi offers.

Answer (score 0):

Three options,

- http://www.yeroon.net/ggplot2/ is an online web based gui to ggplot2 that lets you build your plots interactively.
- [Deducer](http://www.deducer.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Main.DeducerManual) is an R gui that has an interactive graph builder
- [R Studio](http://www.rstudio.org/) has functionality for interactive graph generation.

Comment: To say the Deducer GUI to build plots (via ggplot2) is interactive in this context is misleading. It allows you to choose elements to add to the chart (and update the chart if need be), but it doesn't allow you to interact with elements on the chart (e.g. brushing/linking).